# Exception java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10129 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, permissions, crash

Getting this error on API level 23 and above .

I have already granted READ_PHONE_STATE in Manifest and also add runtime permission for API 23+.

Still getting error.

Comment: check phone setting if app granted permission or not

Comment: yes its granted

Comment: have you tested in other devices?

Comment: yes only occur in API 23+

Comment: i mean other api 23+ devices

Answer (score 1):

Did you do runtime permission request correctly?
please check here
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html